# How to start typing at the second line in edittext?

Tags: java, android

Is there a possibility that my edittext will start typing at the second line? Assuming that the first line was an 'enter'. Is that possible? If that so, how?

This was my code that i'm talking about. Can you find a solution why it keeps on not reading the 1st line. My solution is to make the first line as 'enter' as default. Or you can find another one?

```
public class TestTCP
{
    private static final int PORT = 1475;

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;
    private static String multiple;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT, 0, InetAddress.getLocalHost());

            System.out.println("IP:  " + serverSocket.getInetAddress() + "  Port:  " +  serverSocket.getLocalPort());

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 1447");
        }

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 1447");

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {{
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Message from Table 1: " + message);}
                    inputStreamReader.close();
                    clientSocket.close();}

            } catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    if (bufferedReader != null)bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: May be you can create text box through code and setText() with newline?

Comment: would you give me some sample?

Comment: (or) try  android:defaultValue=" newline character." />. May or may not work.

Comment: Nambari's thought: myTextEdit.setText(" \n");

Comment: Where can i put it? Because my input from edittext comes from tcp socket. I'll update and post my code and see how will i put it. Or you can help me with my code. because it doesn't recognize the 1st line but it does on 2nd,3rd and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
EditText mEditText;
@Override onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    mEditText.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: It works only on first try. But when I click "send", it resets back to the first line.

Comment: When you click send do: mEditText.clear(); and then  mEditText.append("\n");

Answer (score 1):

Set an `ontouch listener` for the `edittext`:

```
editText1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        editText1.setText("\n");
    }
});
```

The editText will skip a line when touched, this code is just an example. You will need to improve it a bit for your needs.

Make sure you refer to this method from the `onCreate method`.

Comment: Having a hard time on where to insert this part of code in my program. :) I am using a socket for this. Can you help me further?

Comment: Hmm this would be more easliy, add: android:paddingTop="10dp" in the .xml file, it will always skip first line.